# Fast copy selected elements of an array in C?

Tags: c

This could be a very basic question but it really bugs me a lot. What I am trying to do is basically to copy elements in an old vector to a new vector using C.

The copy is based on an index vector where each element in this vector represents the index of the element in the old vector. The index vector is not sorted.

For example,
an old vector A = [3.4, 2.6, 1.1].

a index vector B = [1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2].

After copy, I would expect the new vector to be C = [3.4, 3.4, 1.1, 1.1, 2.6, 3.4, 2.6].

The most brutal solution I can think of is to run a loop through B and copy the corresponding element in A to C. But when the vector is too large, the cost is not bearable.

My question is, is there a faster/smarter way to do copy in C on this occasion?

Originally the code is written in Julia and I had no problem with that. In Julia, I simply use C = A[B] and it is fast. Anyone knows how they do it?

Add the C pseudo code:

```
float *A = []; # old array
int *B = []; # index array
float *C;
for(i=0;i<length(B);i++)
{
   *(C+i) = *(A+*(B+i));
}
```

Comment: The `for` loop construct is probably the best you'll get.

Comment: My gut feeling is there may be a smarter way, from what I see when using Julia. Or I may misunderstand something inside.

Comment: This array indexing problem is a notorious performance issue. Fundamentally, it compels the hardware to perform individual unpredictable memory fetches unless either the table array (the one in which data is looked up) is small or there are some patterns to the indices. If the table is small, some processors have SIMD instructions that can speed this up greatly. If there are patterns, solutions depend on the patterns. To get good answers, you should explain the context and give realistic examples, including actual sizes of arrays.

Comment: How fast does Julia do it?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I do not think there are patterns to the indices in my case. What I am doing is to project a numerical variable in a 2D medium to 3D medium in physics. Mathematically, from a smaller array to a larger array. In my current testing, the A array size is 181, the index array B size is about 7000. Julia takes about 0.5ms to do this. My problem can be larger than what I am using now.

Comment: @ZhenhuaLi can you show us the C code that you have implemented?

Comment: @Amadeus I have added how I was doing in C. It is just a brutal for loop.

Comment: @JL2210: I wouldn't bet on it.

Comment: @ZhenhuaLi Is there a reason you write `*(C+i) = *(A+*(B+i))` instead of the obvious code `C[i] = A[B[i]]`?

Comment: Im just more used to pointers.

Comment: @ZhenhuaLi: .5 ms for 7000 lookups on a 1 GHz processor is .5e-3/7000*1e9 = ~71 cycles. That is not fast. C code should definitely be faster even with a simple `for … C[i] = A[B[i]];`.

Comment: What processor are you using? 181 elements of A could fit in AVX-512 registers, and a combination of permute instructions with other selection instructions might be able to do the lookups efficiently.

Comment: The processor I am using is Intel I7-4770.

Comment: Why do you need to make a copy? Could your algorithm work if you just replace `C[i]` with `A[B[i]]` instead?

Comment: If your system is memory bound, then you could be facing swapping effects for the very large memory allocation and memory writing. But, the Julia version should have also faced the same problem when given the same data. Unless you are claiming the C version was slower than Julia for the 7000 item array, then something else is going on and you will need to show more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumption: `length(B)` isn't actually a function but you didn't post what it is. If it is a function, capture it in a local variable outside the `for` loop and read it once; else you have a Schlemiel the Painter's Algorithm.

I think the best we can do is [Duff's Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device) aka loop unrolling. I also made some trivial optimizations the compiler can normally make, but I recall the compiler's loop unrolling isn't *quite* as good as Duff's device. My knowledge could be out of date and the compiler's optimizer could have caught up.

Probing may be required to determine the optimal unroll number. 8 is traditional but your code inside the loop body is larger than normal.

This code is destructive to the pointers `A` and `B`. Save them if you want them again.

```
float *A = []; # old array
int *B = []; # index array
float *C;
int ln = length(B);
int n = (ln + 7) % 8;
switch (n % 8) {
case 0: do { *C++ = A[*B++];
case 7:      *C++ = A[*B++];
case 6:      *C++ = A[*B++];
case 5:      *C++ = A[*B++];
case 4:      *C++ = A[*B++];
case 3:      *C++ = A[*B++];
case 2:      *C++ = A[*B++];
case 1:      *C++ = A[*B++];
    } while (--n > 0);
}
```

With this much scope I can do no better, but with a larger scope a better choice might exist involving redesigning your data structures.